# How to strip all non visible characters from a string, and keep special characters

Tags: c++, string

I know this seems like a duplicate, but I don't believe it is. It's entirely possible that what I'm dealing with is an encoding issue with my provided file format.

Essentially I'm checking for common characters before hashmap insertion. I've got standard input hooked up like so:

```
while(getline(cin, current, ' '){}
```

it outputs properly if you just print what comes in to standard output, but I've got a wild issue where the letter A will always hash to the value of A, but is not considered an A. I know what you're thinking. Whitespace. Well I tried removing whitespace and tabs and spaces. but I think I'm missing some of the invisible characters. I even tried creating a set of acceptable characters and removing non-acceptable characters. Still no luck.

What would be a foolproof way of removing all invisible characters from these input strings? Is that a built in function by chance?

Comment: [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) with the logical not of [`std::isprint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) (or other suitable [character classification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification) function)?

Comment: You can make sure that every character in the string `isalnum` or `ispucnt`.

Comment: Regarding reading input, the `>>` input operator stops reading on space, so you could just as well do `while (std::cin >> current) { ... }`.

Comment: "How to strip all non visible characters from a string, and keep special characters" - most special characters are not visible.

Comment: `for (auto c : s) { if (c >= 0x32 && c < 0x7F) cout << c; else cout << "\\x" << setfill('0') << setw(2) << right << hex << (c & 0xFF); }` ... that will print the visible ASCII characters and anything else as hex (preceded by `\x`).  Presuming on an ASCII platform.

Comment: Thank you @Someprogrammerdude, my experience with strings is minimal, as if I had my choice I'd be using a scripting language to handle string preparations first instead. This is very helpful and I appreciate your assistance immensely. I was unable to find this information elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a string, and you want to remove all non-printing characters from it to ensure it contains only valid printable characters, then you can use the [std::string::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) using [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) coupled with a lambda that negates the result of [std::isprint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) -- to effectively erase all characters from the string that are not printing characters (including whitespace) (as indicated by @someprogrammerdude in his original comment)

A short function to operate on your string to erase all non-printing characters could be:

```
void rm_nonprinting (std::string& str)
{
    str.erase (std::remove_if (str.begin(), str.end(),
                                [](unsigned char c){
                                    return !std::isprint(c);
                                }),
                                str.end());
}
```

At least this would be one way to narrow down why your hash of `'A'` isn't `'A'`.